# Including web page's index.php in another directory.

Tags: php

Assume we have a complete web page in `/web_page/` directory. Now I want to include the index.php file from `/include/` directory, so that `/include/index.php` will show the same web page as in `/web_page/index.php`. There are some problems:

1. This can not be done through iframe.
2. There are a lot of included files in the `/web_page/` directory and simple `require_once()` causes other includes to be not found.

Comment: you can use .htaccess solution

Comment: To make require_once working properly you can use full path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @pes502 suggested, it may be better to do this with .htaccess. Try adding this to a .htacess file in the root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 /include/index.php /web_page/index.php
```

This will send a header that redirects from one page to the other, preventing duplicate pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `../` as 'one folder up'. So include should be like:

`include_once('../include/index.php');`